# Adapting player behaviour to AI in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, state-machine

I have designed an attack method for a player that is full functional, however I am new to AI and have no idea as to where I would begin when it comes to adapting this into a state for an FSM.

```cs
    protected void UpdateAttackState()
    { 
    // check for input
    float rot = transform.localEulerAngles.y + rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    Vector3 fwd = transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    // Tank Chassis is rigidbody, use MoveRotation and MovePosition
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MoveRotation(Quaternion.AngleAxis(rot, Vector3.up));
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(_rigidbody.position + fwd);

        if (turret) {
            Plane playerPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 0));

    // Generate a ray from the cursor position
    Ray RayCast = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    // Determine the point where the cursor ray intersects the plane.
    float HitDist = 0;

            // If the ray is parallel to the plane, Raycast will return false.
            if (playerPlane.Raycast(RayCast, out HitDist))
            {
                // Get the point along the ray that hits the calculated distance.
                Vector3 RayHitPoint = RayCast.GetPoint(HitDist);

    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(RayHitPoint - transform.position);
    turret.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(turret.transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime* turretRotSpeed);
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            if (elapsedTime >= shootRate)
            {
                //Reset the time
                elapsedTime = 0.0f;

                //Also Instantiate over the PhotonNetwork
                if ((bulletSpawnPoint) & (bullet))
                    Instantiate(bullet, bulletSpawnPoint.transform.position, bulletSpawnPoint.transform.rotation);
            }
        }

        // Update the time
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is completely dependent on how you want your state machine to work. An example of this would be the AI trying to seek and destroy other players.

Seeking State: AI would move around the map with a detection zone (collider) that would change state on trigger enter. This would then save a position of the detection's generalized location which would be used to move and rotate the AI tank towards that position.

Firing State: AI enters a new detection zone (collider) within firing range, turret will move to aim at target. AI will also move around the map to keep firing range at a maximum while also keeping track of the last known position of the enemy if they happen to go out of range.

Detecting Fire: Player or other AI fires their weapon this could increase the detection radius resulting in a seeking state being called.

After those functions are figured out, place a switch or something similar within the Update() to allow everything within the AI to run alongside Unity's functions.